# can I get access token through LinknedIn JS SDK?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

new to LinkedIn OAuth development, I want to use its JS SDK to implement login, but I can not find a way to get the `access_token` after I login successfully.

Does LinkedIn JS SDK has some API to get it ? Just like [facebook javascript api does](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#token).

Thank you !

Comment: I have the same problem